# A simple optimization problem

Tags: optimization

I am trying to derive ELM going through the basics , please help me out here :

$$f = x^Tx$$
$$g = Ax-b $$

The constraint is $Ax-b = 0$

I calculated $J' = f'+\lambda^T g'$
which is $2x+(\lambda^T A)^T = 0 $ and $Ax-b=0$ .
I dont know what to do next please help me out .

Comment: Please tell us what ELM means. It looks like you are asking for help solving a Lagrange multiplier problem, right?

Comment: Extreme Learning Machine

Comment: That term is irrelevant , its just an optimization problem

Comment: answer should $x = pseudoinverse(A)b$ but I am not able to derive it

Comment: This is solved in many, many places on this site: the key is to recognize that your are trying to solve the least squares equations and the solutions are given by [normal equations](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+equations).  Follow the links in this search for your choice of demonstrations.  I'll close this thread and provide a link to the first hit in the search (ordered by relevance).

Comment: TrafalgarLaw - it may  help to check out the link that whuber suggests, and if it's still not clear, to ask a much more specific question.